# Dynamically adding components in multiple columns & legend creation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a fieldset to witch I add components dynamically code looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend style="color:blue;font-weight:bold;">#{msgs.newsletterConstantPersonalization}</legend>
            <ui:repeat var="personalizedProp" value="#{newsletterWflBean.constantPersonalizationProperties}">
                <comp:embeddedLabel label="#{personalizedProp.name}">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{personalizedProp.used}" />
                </comp:embeddedLabel>
            </ui:repeat>
        </fieldset>
```

However every component appear beneath previews one. I would like to create fix amount of columns eg. 3 and place new components side by side.

So, now it looks like this:

```
comp1
comp2
comp3
...
compx
```

What I want for eg. 3 columns:

```
comp1 comp2 comp3
comp4 comp5 comp6
...
compx compx+1 ...
```

(where comp is label+checkbox)

How can I achieve that with JSF? I don't want to create a list of lists and duplicate ui:repeat tag. I wan't to keep view separate from business logic. So I would like everything to be done in JSF/JavaScript.

Also with legend tag I assume (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp) I should have nice title border around my components but that doesn't work. Why? How to create title border/legend using JSF?

Thanks for help

Comment: Thanks @BalusC dataGrid was exactly what I was looking for. However I still can't manage to create titled border/legend around my dataGrid. Why legend tag doesn't work like in case of plain HTML?

Comment: http://htmldog.com/references/html/tags/legend *"The element should appear directly after the opening fieldset tag."*. The dataGrid component doesn't generate a fieldset tag. Use another tag to represent a legend, e.g. h2/h3/h4. This has not much to do with JSF.

Comment: In my generated HTML <legend> tag actually appears right after <fieldset> tag. It looks like this: <fieldset><legend>Constant Personalization</legend> ...[STUFF GENERATED FROM dataGrid]</fieldset>. So I wander if legend tag doesn't work with some other HTML tags? Not only border is missing but even "Constant Personalization" text is not rendered.

Comment: Ok, now I understand that the border comes from styling fieldset element rather than from legend element. It actually make more sense. Moreover, in the project I took over legend element was styled to not display at all.  Charms of being a newbie in a big project :). Anyway, @BalusC thank you for your help and sorry about confusion around this topic.